# hide the child rows if opened and toggle All child rows on expand all button click

Tags: jquery

`ExpandAll` button  is not triggering properly . If any child row is shown  before `ExpandAll` button click  it hides that particular row and it shows the remaining child rows .

But I want this to work like if on  click of `ExpandAll` button  if any child row is opened it should be shown along with others and closes along with others.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#ExpandAll', function() {
  $('#Table > tbody > tr[class*=child]').each(function() {

    $(this).toggle();


  });
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.BundleExpand', function() {

  var className = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class');
  var number = parseFloat(className.match(/-*[0-9]+/));

  if ($('.child' + number + ':visible').length)
    $('.child' + number).hide();
  else
    $('.child' + number).show();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default " id="ExpandAll">
Expand All
</button>
<table id="Table" class="table table-bordered table-stripped">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parent1">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BundleExpand">Expand One</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child1" style="display:none">
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent2">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BundleExpand">Expand One</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child2" style="display:none">
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent3">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BundleExpand">Expand One</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child3" style="display:none">
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

any suggestions please. Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your selector within the expand all listener to eliminate visible children:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#ExpandAll', function() {

  var affectedChildren =  $('#Table > tbody > tr[class*=child]:not(:visible)');

  if( affectedChildren.length ==0)
  {
    affectedChildren =  $('#Table > tbody > tr[class*=child]');
  }

  affectedChildren.each(function() {
    $(this).toggle();
  });

});
```

Comment: Yeah i have added your code . it shows all but it 's not hiding back all

Answer (score 1):

try adding something like the code below

```
if (s === 0) {
  $(this).toggle()
} else if (s === m) {
    $(this).toggle();
} else {
  if (!$(this).is(":visible"))
    $(this).toggle();
  }
```

`s` and `m` comes from:

```
var s = $('#Table > tbody > tr[class*=child]:visible').length;
var m = $('#Table > tbody > tr[class*=child]').length;
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#ExpandAll', function() {
  var s = $('#Table > tbody > tr[class*=child]:visible').length;
  var m = $('#Table > tbody > tr[class*=child]').length;
  $('#Table > tbody > tr[class*=child]').each(function() {

    if (s === 0) {
      $(this).toggle()
    } else if (s === m) {
        $(this).toggle();
    } else {
      if (!$(this).is(":visible"))
        $(this).toggle();
      }



  });
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.BundleExpand', function() {

  var className = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class');
  var number = parseFloat(className.match(/-*[0-9]+/));

  if ($('.child' + number + ':visible').length)
    $('.child' + number).hide();
  else
    $('.child' + number).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-default " id="ExpandAll">
Expand All
</button>
<table id="Table" class="table table-bordered table-stripped">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parent1">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BundleExpand">Expand One</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child1" style="display:none">
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent2">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BundleExpand">Expand One</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child2" style="display:none">
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent3">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BundleExpand">Expand One</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child3" style="display:none">
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle for both opening and closing:

```js
var visible = false;

$(document).on('click', '#ExpandAll', function() {
  visible = !visible;
  $('#Table > tbody > tr[class*=child]').each(function() {
    if(visible && !$(this).is(":visible")){
      $(this).toggle();
    } else if(!visible && $(this).is(":visible")) {
      $(this).toggle();
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.BundleExpand', function() {
  var className = $(this).closest('tr').attr('class');
  var number = parseFloat(className.match(/-*[0-9]+/));

  if ($('.child' + number + ':visible').length)
    $('.child' + number).hide().removeClass("shown");
  else
    $('.child' + number).show().addClass("shown");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default " id="ExpandAll">
Expand All
</button>
<table id="Table" class="table table-bordered table-stripped">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parent1">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BundleExpand">Expand One</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child1" style="display:none">
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent2">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BundleExpand">Expand One</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child2" style="display:none">
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent3">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BundleExpand">Expand One</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child3" style="display:none">
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```